# Reputation tab and graph

Tags: bug, reputation

Normally when you click on the Reputation Tab of your user profile you have 3 options to display with Post, Time, or Graph.

Unfortunately, lately I haven't been able to use the Graph option to click-and-drag an area across the lower chart to zoom in on particular areas of the graph.

Does anyone else have this problem or is it to be fixed in the near future?

---

### UPDATE

I'm still having the same issue as of December 2015.

Comment: worksforme™, are you using the mobile version or the full one?

Comment: Browser/OS information would likely help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I'm using Google Chrome on a Samsung computer.